# Symfony 4 - Flatpickr parse date

Tags: php, symfony, datetime, parsing, flatpickr

in my Symfony 4 project, I'm using the flatpickr plugin for datetime. https://flatpickr.js.org/

So in my formType, my date field is in Text format:

```
->add('date', TextType::class, [
    'label' => "Date de la mission",
    'attr'=> [
        'placeholder' => "Date de la mission"
    ],
])
```

But in my entity, it's a datetime.

So, how can I parse it before submitting to give a datetime ? Because in the view, it's a string.
I seen this : https://flatpickr.js.org/instance-methods-properties-elements/#useful-static-methods

But I don't understand how can I apply it...

For the moment, I've :

```
<script>
    $("#ordre_mission_date").flatpickr({
        enableTime: true,
        dateFormat: "d/m/Y H:i",
        locale: "fr",
        time_24hr: true,
    });
</script>
```

Can someone help me please ?

Comment: Nobody to help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your `date` field definition. Instead of `TextType`, use the  `DateTimeType`:

```
->add('date', DateTimeType::class, [
    'label' => "Date de la mission",
    'widget' => 'single_text',
    'attr'=> [
        'placeholder' => "Date de la mission"
    ],
])
```

The line `'widget' => 'single_text'` will render the DateTime field as a single `<input type="text"/>`, allowing you to use your plugin.